# Get file content from response object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

They should be really simple. A api returns the file content of an excel file at just want to save it.

```
response = session.get(url, params=params)
print(response.content)
> b'{"success":true,"message":null,"payload":"UEsDBBQAAAgIAEF1 - many lines - AACAdAAAAAA==","fileName":"Mi Report 21-06-2021 - 22-06-2021"}'
```

I tried

```
output = r'C:\Users\Developer\Downloads\test.xlsx'
content = response.json()['payload'].encode('ascii')
with open(output, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)

with open(output, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content[42:-49])
```

But it always ends up in a corrupted excel file. Any hints appreciated

Comment: `payload`  seems base64 encoded.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the file as a CSV? I think xlsx files are encoded as XML.

Comment: have you tried `f.write(base64.decode(response.json()['payload']))`?

Comment: Thank you! that was it. If one of you wants to write this up as an answer, I can then accepted it

Comment: if `base64` decode option worked, then @Maurice Meyer deserve to answer this question. I only pasted the snippet to decode the ascii string